# populate form field with current values

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a form for creating and updating the rental space. For creating, it is working ok but for updating the form is shown empty. Rather it should show the current value in the fields. How can i now populate the field with current values when updating?

Here is what i have done

```
url(r'^rents(?:/(?P<token>[0-9a-z]+))?', Rent.as_view(), name="rent"),

class RentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Rental
        read_only = ('id', 'token', 'created_on', 'modified_on', 'slug', )
        fields = ('__all__')

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        return str(obj.owner)

    def create(self, validated_data): #same as update just change to .create()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance = super(RentSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

views.py

```
class Rent(APIView):
    """
    List all the rents if token is not provided else a token specific rent
    """
    serializer_class = RentSerializer
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        reply={}
        try:
            rents = Rental.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            if token:
                rent = rents.get(token=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rent).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rents, many=True).data
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        rent = None
        # if token is None, its a list new rent
        if not token is None:
            try:
                rent = Rental.objects.filter(owner=request.user).get(token=token)
            except Rental.DoesNotExist:
                return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
            except:
                return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        serialized_data = self.serializer_class(instance=rent, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serialized_data.is_valid():
            serialized_data.save(owner=request.user)
        else:
            return error.ValidationError(serialized_data.errors).as_response()
        reply={}
        reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(instance=rent, many=False).data
        return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I dont want to use viewset. How can i do this using APIView?

Comment: You would need to show the view that creates the form and the template for the form to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sorry i did not get you. Do i have to work on template part when using rest-framework? I mean if i want to see as browsable api of rest_framework. This is the complete code i have shown you.